# Efficient way of storing data using Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am working on an application for storing trees. From what I have read in a book about graph databases/neo4j is that the relationships should not be duplicated.

For example if there exists a relation such as `(a)-[friend_of]->(b)`, then `(b)-[friend_of]->(a)` would be useless, because it can be easily queried both directions even though the relation is oriented. In Spring Data Neo4j documentation I wasn't able to find any way of dealing with this which would mean that the developer is forced to implement inefficient data storing.
Which is why I have considered using other abstractions such as Neo4jTemplate, Neo4jClient or OGM framework. I couldn't find any info on handling the relation in the documentations.

Now I am thinking of creating an implementation of my own, that is writing queries for the objects and persisting the relations.

How could I handle mapping the query result to Java objects with the relations? Right now this is the part that's stopping my progress.

If there is any way of obtaining this result using the tools mentioned, please mention them too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could define the relationship again with incoming direction in the entity.

```
@Relationship(type = "PARTNER_OF")
var partners: MutableSet<Person> = mutableSetOf()

@Relationship(value = "PARTNER_OF", direction = Direction.INCOMING)
var partnersIncoming: MutableSet<Person> = mutableSetOf() // worst naming ever
```

But be aware that any changes to the relationship between two persons need to be in sync.

If you want to query this with a custom Cypher query, something like this

```
MATCH (person:Person)-[partnerOfRelation:PARTNER_OF]-(partner:Person) RETURN person, collect(partnerOfRelation), collect(partner)
```

would make a good starter.

(copied and combined my answers from https://community.neo4j.com/t/efficient-way-of-storing-relations-sdn6/46879 to make it available here)